# Add persistence.xml to to jar with SBT?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, sbt

I have a Java SBT project with my hibernate config located at `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml`

What do I need to put in build.sbt to add that file to my jar so hibernate can pick-it-up?

I've tried:

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
mappings in Universal ++= contentOf(baseDirectory.value / "conf/META-INF")
```

**Note**: `PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false` as mentioned [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) does add it to the jar, but it breaks other things like Logback so this is not an option.

Comment: I'd say what you ask is not an option and it would be far easier to look if you can repair all 'other things'...

Comment: Just to add, what you'll have to do to 'fix' this would be to get the META-INF folder on the classpath or get Hibernate to look inside the conf directory. There are some suggestions in this comment on github: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4590#issuecomment-117051996, though people have had issues with all of them.